# How to compare mac-addresses in Perl

Tags: perl, comparison, mac-address

I had two mac addresses 12-23-34-RT-43-23 and 12:23:34:rt:43:23. How to compare these two mac address in Perl. Are there any libraries to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about normalization, make them both upper case, and convert `-` to `:`,

```
my $mac1 = "12-23-34-RT-43-23";
my $mac2 = "12:23:34:rt:43:23";

y|[a-z]-|[A-Z]:| for $mac1, $mac2;

print "equal\n" if $mac1 eq $mac2;
```

Comment: Are there any perl libraries? And can u explain the line "y|[a-z]-|[A-Z]:| for $mac1, $mac2;" once.